# How run php script on mac for desktop application

Tags: php, macos, titanium

I've just started using Titanium Studio. When I use PHP code in my desktop applications, it is not parsed at run time on MacOS. The output is the same as the PHP source code. I have tried:

```
<?php 
  phpinfo(); 
?>
```

and

```
<script type="text/php" >
   phpinfo();
</script>
```

I have built this application on Window and ran it and it works fine. But on the MacOS, PHP code is not parsed. When I tried to create & build PHP desktop applications on MacOS it gives me an exception.

Please help me regarding this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: do you install any server ? for ex.mamp server for mac

Comment: no server needed.. But I believe Mac OS is still buggy..

Comment: Did you enable apache (turn on web sharing) and enable the PHP module by uncommenting it in httpd.conf?

Comment: Titanium PHP is no longer active and frankly too complicated! Take a look at PHP Nightrain, it is opensource, portable and works out of box on Mac, Windows and Linux. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXt8erPLf4o

Answer (score 2):

Similar problem i also faced few days back. What i did is I downloaded Titanium Desktop SDK 1.2.0 RC6 (Which is compatible with lion, i think RC5 is also compatible with lion).

Than I run same code in lion instead of snow leopard. It's working all fine for me now. And one more thing you have to include external php file. In my case inline php was not working on MAC so I included external PHP file and all is fine now.

Comment: Thanks Harsh, Topener, GordonM, The Zero. I use Titanium Desktop SDK 1.2.0 RC6. But still php not run on Mac. My output are follows on Window & mac:   http://i1095.photobucket.com/albums/i472/libbyamala/phpapps7WINDOWSEXE-INDEX.jpg http://i1095.photobucket.com/albums/i472/libbyamala/phpapps7WINDOWSEXE-INFO.jpg http://i1095.photobucket.com/albums/i472/libbyamala/phpapps7MAC-INDEX.png http://i1095.photobucket.com/albums/i472/libbyamala/phpapps7MAC-INFO.png

Comment: Than i have no idea bro. I have told you the way i have solved my error. There is no other way i know. Sorry.